# Issue with Div Tags Aligning

Tags: html, css

**EDIT:** I believe I've resolve this myself. The "body-container" Div required "overflow: hidden". Thanks to those who gave assistance.

I'm designing a website which I plan to convert into a Wordpress template in the future. My current issue I'm running into is the background of the Div containing my "news" Div and my "sidebar" Div disappearing whenever I float the "sidebar" Div. I've been working at it for a few hours now, but can't seem to find the problem.

[Here's the web page in question.](http://ev-gaming.net/testing/Theme/)

HTML:

```
<div id="body">
<div id="body-container">
    <div id="news">
        <div id="post-1" class="news-posts">
            Post 1
        </div>
        <div id="post-2" class="news-posts">
            Post 2
        </div>
        <div id="post-3" class="news-posts">
            Post 3
        </div>
        <div id="post-4" class="news-posts">
            Post 4
        </div>
        <div id="post-5" class="news-posts">
            Post 5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
            #body-container {
        margin: 0 auto 0;
        height: auto;
        width: 1060px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 5px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0pt 0pt 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 5px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0pt 0pt 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
        box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 5px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0pt 0pt 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
        background: #9A9A9A;
        border: thin solid black;
    }
    #news {
        height: auto;
        width: 735px;
        padding: 5px;
        float: left;
    }
    #sidebar {
        height: 500px;
        width: 200px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 5px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0pt 0pt 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 5px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0pt 0pt 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
        box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 5px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0pt 0pt 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
        background: #FFF;
        clear: right;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        float: right;
    }
    .news-posts {
        height: 200px;
        width: 636px;
        background: #FFF;
        padding: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 5px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0pt 0pt 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 5px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0pt 0pt 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
        box-shadow: 0pt 0pt 5px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0pt 0pt 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) inset;
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with that in it?

Comment: http://ev-gaming.net/testing/Theme - That's the entire page, what I posted initially was the part giving me issues. The "body-container" Div has a background you should be able to see, but can't because the "sidebar" Div set to float right.

Comment: it's working fine http://jsfiddle.net/mikulgohil/cLr4V/

Comment: Well if you look, that black line at the top is actually the border for the "body-container" Div which should be going around everything. You'll also see that the background is not present, which is the issue I've described.

Comment: remove all height, if u need a wapper use "clear:both"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "body-container" Div required "overflow: hidden".